# Python os.system() automaticly exit when command is not finished yet

Tags: python, os.system

Currently I am using the python `os.system(cmd)` to do some daily works.

Here is one situation, the cmd will take 5-6 minutes to finish, and I run this cmd maually, it works, but when I put it into `os.system(cmd)`, `os.system(cmd)` will automatically exit when the cmd is not finished yet.

So my question is: how to handle this issue, set timeout value or there is any better way to finish this job ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes, thanks Michael. I check the document and no result found, can you provide some url or some info here, many thanks a lot

Comment: What does the `cmd` string look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the `subprocess` module?  It was added to replace `os.system` among other older `os` methods.  The following is pretty much straight from the docs:

```
import os
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True)
pid, sts = os.waitpid(proc.pid, 0)

# you may check on this process later and kill it if it's taking too long
if proc.poll() in [whatever, ...]:
    os.kill(proc.pid)
```

or if you're trying to debug why the process is exiting:

```
import subprocess
import sys

try:
    retcode = subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True)
    if retcode < 0:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Child was terminated by signal", -retcode
    else:
        print >>sys.stderr, "Child returned", retcode
except OSError, e:
    print >>sys.stderr, "Execution failed:", e
```

Comment: Thanks mVchr, you are so quick. I just try your ways in my Env. There are some questions: 1: In my env, return code 233, what does it means? 2 And actually cmd I mationed in the question, it is one shell script (*.bin), using the python to call and ./***.bin, is there any different? Thanks a lot

Comment: 1: This is not a standard shell exit code that I know of, so you would have to consult the process(es) you are running... 2: It depends on what's set in your #!